# How to check the duplicate row with multiple column in infopath repeating table

Tags: infopath

I want to check the duplicate row with three columns(ProductID,ProductName,ProductCategory). So user should not  enter duplicate row with the same ProductID,ProductName and ProductCategory(with these 3 combination). ex1:

```
ProductID    ProductName    ProductCategory
1            Aciloc150      Medicine
```

User should be restricted to enter the above same ProductID,ProductName and ProductCategory(1            Aciloc150      Medicine)

I know the below code using this I can check the duplicate value in one column, How can I check the duplicate row with the above combination(ProductID    ProductName    ProductCategory)?

```
 count(/my:myFields/my:group1/my:group2[my:field2 != ""]) > 1 and (. = ../preceding-sibling::my:group2/my:field2 or . = ../following-sibling::my:group2/my:field2)
```

Here /my:myFields/my:group1/my:group2 -> repeating group xpath

My:field2 -> field in repeating table

Comment: So do you want to prevent having two rows that have all three values in common, or prevent rows that have _any_ value in common? E.g. is this invalid: `[1, Aciloc150, Medicine], [2, Aciloc150, Equipment]`, or just this: `[1, Aciloc150, Medicine], [1, Aciloc150, Medicine]`?

Comment: @JLRishe:Thanks, I wanted to avoid this:[1, Aciloc150, Medicine], [1, Aciloc150, Medicine]. Anyway I am done with this, it may help others as well. Create one hidden field in the repeating table and concat these 3 fields and apply the above validation formula on the hidden filed, It works like charm.

Comment: Glad to see that you solved it on your own. You should post that as an answer down below. If you're going to use that approach, I would recommend concatenating them with a separator character (such as `|` or `+`) to ensure against the rare case that there is overlap between the three fields (for example, to use a contrived example, to distinguish between `1|Aciloc150|Medicine` and `1|Aciloc150M|edicine`).